# Como reajusto o label de um gráfico chart js?

Tags: javascript, c#, chartjs

Como ajusto o tamanho da fonte do label ou coloco uma quebra de linha? O texto não está cabendo por completo, para monitor 1080 cabe, mas 720 acontece isso.

[image: Como ajusto o tamanho da fonte do label ou coloco uma quebra de linha?]

Meu código:

```
<script>
    var myChartcaixa = new Chart(document.getElementById("caixa-chart"), {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels:  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => x.Descricao).ToArray())),
            datasets: [{
                data:  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => x.Valor).ToArray())),
                backgroundColor: backgroudColor,
                borderWidth: 1,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: false,
        }
    }); </script>
```

Comment: Mesmo tirando algumas colunas da table o label do chart não saí da área do próprio chart, mesmo tendo espaço a direita para que a frase caiba ela continua sendo cortada.

Comment: Inspecione o elemento e veja o que aborda ele, coloque no css a propriedade
 word-wrap:  break-word

se não der porque é carregado depois, depois que carregar o grafico, insira via jquery